# Get line number of called function C

Tags: c, line-numbers

Is there a way to get the line number a function was called on in C without doing anything like below?
The define can make it tedious after a while, having to use DP instead of { like usual, and hard to read; but the adding **LINE** as the first parameter to every function is just something I'm not willing to do.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdarg.h>
    #define println(x,...) printf(x,##__VA_ARGS__);printf("\n");
    /*
     *I would like to be able to replace __LINE__ with the line
     *each function was called on, or replace my DP define completely...
    */
    #ifdef _DEBUG_
        #define DP { println("%s:%d\t%s()",__FILE__,__LINE__,__FUNCTION__);
    #else
        #define DP {
    #endif
    void calledFunc()
    DP
        println("something something something");
    }
    void cFunc(int line)
    {
        println("%s:%d\t%s()",__FILE__,line,__FUNCTION__);
    }
    int main()
    DP
        calledFunc();
        /* ...and I don't want to have to do this all the time either*/
        cFunc(__LINE__);
    }
```

Comment: Why, really? Compile the program with debug symbols - the debugger will show line numbers.

Comment: I don't use a debugger, and don't plan on it.

Comment: What platform are you on? You can usually get some stack symbols on most platforms that may help you.

Comment: @Andrew you should really be using a debugger.

Comment: @Richard I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, not exactly sure how I would do that though.

Comment: @H2CO3 If you could point me to a good command line debugger be my guest, although I'd still much rather not use a debugger someone else made. I'm also trying to do this to learn myself so.

Comment: @Andrew: [gdb](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/).

Comment: @Andrew Why not use a debugger someone else wrote? You are using an OS someone else wrote, and compiler someone else wrote, a linker someone else wrote, a version of libc someone else wrote?

Comment: @Adrian I would rather use something I made so that way I can have had the experience of making whatever it is. In this case I've been trying to debug something of mine (unexpected output), and with a lot of calls to certain functions it's hard to tell where it originated from. I figured while I'm doing this I could learn something else useful on the way. But thanks anyways for your input I suppose.

Comment: @Andrew I totally get the wanting to write stuff yourself - but for example gdb is 12 years old - has over 300 developers and approx 2.7 million lines of code. With gdb I have debugged many many things that would have been impossible otherwise. It is a wise addition to your skillset. With wise use of gdb you can take snapshots of running processes, set hardware break points to find the bit of code that alters a variable and many many other cool things. You can do things with gdb that you cannot with logging.

Comment: Wanted to add it took me many many years to resist reinventing the wheel ;-)

Comment: @Andrew: Without a debugger, you wont get far in C or C++. I learned that the hard way.

Comment: I would take the { out of the definition and just have it resolve to nothing when it is not debug.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good substitute for printing the line file name/number. It is called "LocationID" or LID.

LID is a number that is generated out the project wide counter. The latest value of the counter should be stored in the source file and checked in/out of the source control system like any other source file. The value of the counter can be scrambled. This forces its proper use. You use it like:

```
   #ifdef _DEBUG_
        #define DP(x, msg) println("%d: %s", x, msg);
   #endif
```

and in your source:

```
DP (3517, "Here we are.")
```

Advantage of the LIDs are:

1. They are stable against modification of the source file, including renaming of the file/function.
2. They are easy to find in the sources.
3. Log file is much more compact and clear than with the file name and the function name.

I used this several times and it proved to be good. Generation and distribution of LID values among developers is an overhead, but the result is 10 times worth the price of this effort.